# How to call oracle dbms_scheduler.run_job from java?

Tags: java, oracle, jobs, dbms-scheduler

I have a job in my oracle database and for some reason i need to call it within my java application.
Anyone has an idea to tell me how?
I already tried:
**execute DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('My_job_name')

DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('My_job_name')

{DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('My_job_name')}

{execute DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('My_job_name')}**

by **CallableStatement** but none of them worked.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What error messages have you received when trying these? Have you tried the command in Toad or SQL*Plus to make sure you have the syntax and privs correct on the database side?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the scheduler call in a BEGIN-END block:

```
CallableStatement callStmt = conn.prepareCall(
  "BEGIN DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(job_name => 'My_job_name'); END;");
callStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the priviliges do run it?
if yes i guess that the job must be disabled
Run the following procedure to enable it :

```
exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE (My_job_name);
```

And let me know what you got.